# How to Accept this types of inputs in c?

Tags: c

Input :
4 5 6 7 8
20
15

I need to accept one Integer Array.Array size is not given.And I also want to accept two integer values below the input Array.
How to I Proceed these types of problems in C.

- Code:

```
   int a[1001],x,y;
   int i=0;
   while(scanf("%d ",&a[i])==1){
   i++
   }
   scanf("%d\n%d",&x,&y);
```

Comment: How is the "end" of the array input defined? All you seem to have is a sequence of integers, how do you know which ones are "below"?

Comment: If all you care about is the last two inputs that were written into the array you can just access them via indices?

Comment: @UnholySheep looks like OP is expecting a newline character, without a carriage return character, and then another 2 integers. Most likely that's what's going wrong as depending on operating system that may or may not be what they are getting, especially on Windows/DOS you'd be getting both \n and \r which would break this

Comment: @UnholySheep now see my input

Comment: Using `scanf` it will be hard to only read from one line as it automatically skips whitespace. You could try to read the first line using `fgets` and count the numbers from the read buffer. Then allocate the array for the values and parse the numbers from the buffer.

Comment: Ditch `scanf()` from your toolbox. Prefer `fgets()` or `getchar()`. See https://ideone.com/QAOWZz

Comment: @Sakthi Manikandan, Is input like 123-456" acceptable? (2 numbers separated by a sign and not a space)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No..

Comment: @SakthiManikandan So `"%d\n%d"` is no good to read into `x` and then `y` as that accepts "123-456".

Answer (score 0):

**To read a line of up to N `int`s into an array**

- Better to use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input. Avoid `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.
- Defensive coding will detect overlong lines, values outside `int` range and non-numeric input.  Suggest 2x size buffers for user input.
- Avoid naked magic numbers.
- To do a good job takes a bit of code, but not too much.

```
// UNTESTED ILLUSTRATIVE CODE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_N  1001
#define CHAR_PER_INT 11

// Return a number of `int`s read.
// Return -1 on error.
int read_1_line_of_ints(int n, int a[]) {
  // Form a buffer 2x enough for worse-case input.
  #define BUF_N (ARRAY_N * (CHAR_PER_INT + 1) * 2 + 1 + 1)
  char buf[BUF_N];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return 0; // No input
  }
  const char *p = buf;
  int i = 0;
  while (*p) {
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    long value = strtol(p, &end, 10);
    if (p == end) {|
      // No conversion
      if (*p == '\n') {
        break;
      }
      // Non numeric input
      return -1;
    }
    if (errno || value > INT_MAX || value < INT_MIN) {
      // Value out of int range
      return -1;
    }
    if (i >= n) {
      // Too many
      return -1;
    }
    if (*p - buf + 1 >= sizeof buf) {
      // We are too close to the end and 
      // may have failed to read in all the number.
      return -1;
    } 
    a[i++] = (int) value;
    p = end;
  }
  return i;
}

// Usage

    int n = sizeof a/sizeof a[0];
    int count = read_1_line_of_ints(n, a);
```

This handle many issues.  Some yet to do:

- How to handle even more than `ARRAY_N` inputs?
- What to do when even `buf[BUF_N]` is not enough?
- Allowing other white-space than `'\n'` after the last value.
- ... (There is always a few more)

---

**To read input `x, y`**

Read into an array size of 1, twice

```
read_1_line_of_ints(1, &x); 
read_1_line_of_ints(1, &y);
```

I'll review deeper tomorrow and provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

You are reading values into the array with your while cycle independently of whether the actual value belongs to the array or not. You will need to check `scanf` whether it matches the end of the input in your while cycle and you will also need to check whether the character after the int value is newline or something else:

```
   int a[1001],x = -1,y = -1,temp;
   char tempC = ' ';
   int i=0;
   while(scanf("%d%c",&temp, &tempC) == 2){
       if (tempC == '\n') {
           if (x == -1) x = temp;
           else y = temp;
       } else {
           a[i++] = temp;
       }
   }
```

Comment: suggestion: `while(scanf("%d%c", &temp, &tempC) == 2)`